# Managing database routers in Django

Tags: python, django, database

I am new to Django and am trying to create a simple CRUD for an existing table in a database.

The thing is, that database is not local and I do not want Django to create its built-in tables in it -- I want it to create its tables in a local database. The correct way to do that is by using database routers, right?

I created an app **myapp**, and declared the external table I want to write the CRUD for in its `models.py`.

Now, I have written two routers (in two separate files) -- one that routes **myapp** to the external database (the `DataRouter`), and another one that routes all other requests to the local database (the `SystemRouter`). Is that the correct way to do that? Where should I place those files? I have tried placing them in multiple different directories inside my project, but can't make the DATABASE_ROUTERS list in `settings.py` find them.

For example, if I place them in the root directory for the project and make:

`DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['DataRouter', 'SystemRouter']`

I get:

`ImportError: DataRouter doesn't look like a module path`

I am really lost. Is that the best way to solve my problem? How do I route the data correcty?

Comment: Your use case looks a bit weird. Do you really need django? May be it will be enough to use just ORM (like [peewee](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee))?

Comment: No, I am not sure I even need Django -- I just thought it would be the simplest approach. Thanks, I'm gonna have a look at peewee!